# how to change content in div, without over writing current content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought this one would be easy, but after an hour of googling, i still haven't found anything.

I know how to update content in a div with jquery:

```
$(".div").html("stuff");
```

but that replaces the current content in the DIV (over writes it). I need the current content to remain there.

I don't mind if you know a way in Javascript or Jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `append()`, `prepend()` or `html()`'s inbuilt function:

```
$('div').html(
    function(index,oldhtml){
        var newString = 'something';
        $(this).html(newString + ' ' + oldhtml);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wVFL6/1/).

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

Comment: Honestly, serializing to `.html()` and back is really the worst solution. I don't see any reason to not use `.append()`/`.prepend()`.

Comment: Neither do I, but since `append()` and `prepend()` had already been covered (and shown in the linked demo), I felt I should cover the only other (easy) solution I could think of.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for `.append()`

Answer (score 0):

Concat?

```
var old_content = $(".div").html();
$(".div").html(old_content + "newstuff");
```